# CSV file opened with newline='' - why?

Tags: python, csv

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

> If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''.

Why? I have tested it both ways and it seems to work equally well either way. Are there some semi-valid CSV files that will work only if the above instruction is followed?

Comment: Python 2.7 or 3+?

Comment: The explanation is directly linked after that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3) on the page:

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n`
>   linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be
>   safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own
>   ([universal](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)) newline handling.